# Unable to even find drive after erasing an encrypted drive

Tags: macos, disk-utility, install

I messed up and erased my drive using Disk Utility by doing <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.

Afterward, I wanted to reinstall macOS. Except now when I go to Disk Utility the only thing it sees is the image that I booted into. `diskutil list` doesn't even show it.

Comment: Adding a picture of what your screen shows might help to understand the question better. Also, did you try to proceed with Recovery by reinstalling the OS?

Comment: What model of Mac is this?